# How to forbid traces under component in Diptrace?

Tags: diptrace

If anybody is using DipTrace in auto-routing shape mode, is there any way to tell not to put traces under certain components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Diptrace, but look for "keepout" in the documentation.  You want to define keepout areas for each component.

An alternate way to do this is to draw copper shapes under each component, such that the autorouter will not be able to use that space.  Then delete the shapes after autorouting.

Comment: Anyway, keepout still allows vias under component and hence traces...

Comment: @Pablo: This is correct. Vias are allowed in keepouts since they're usually needed for routing.

Comment: Is there not also a via keepout?